# ReactInstanceManager caught exception in setupReactContext

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to pass an object from Android to React Native through using putParceableArrayList. However, I am getting the error:

```
ReactInstanceManager caught exception in setupReactContext
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value type class com.reactnative.helpers.Student
```

My React activity is the following:

```
public class MyReactActivity extends ReactActivity  implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        
        Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        studentList.add(new Student("John Doe", "Javascript"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Jane Doe", "Typescript"));
        //studentList.add(gson.toJson(new Student("John Doe", "Javascript")));//Original attempt works but passes JSON string

        initialProperties.putSerializable("studentList", (Serializable) studentList);// Throws error as well. Below the error
        //initialProperties.putStringArrayList("studentList", studentList);// Original attempt  works but passes JSON string
        
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "RNProject", initialProperties);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
}
```

The object to be passed from Android to React Native:

Student.java:

```
package com.reactnative.helpers;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(){}

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{name="+name+",course="+course+"}";
    }

    public Student(String name, String course){
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

However, when running the application I got the following error when starting the React Native:

```
Unknown value type class com.reactnative.helpers.Student
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value type class com.reactnative.helpers.Student
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromList(Arguments.java:271)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle(Arguments.java:314)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1273)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1185)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.-$$Nest$msetupReactContext(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1139)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

If I use `Parceable` in Student Object:

```
package com.reactnative.helpers;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class Student implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(){}

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{name="+name+",course="+course+"}";
    }

    public Student(String name, String course){
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }
    
    
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(course);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Student>() {
        public Student createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Student(source);
        }
        @Override
        public Student[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Student[size];
        }
    };

    public Student(Parcel in){
        name= in.readString();
        course = in.readString();
    }
}
```

and replace `Serializable` in MyReactActivity:

```
initialProperties.putParcelableArrayList("studentList", studentList);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value type class ca.bc.gov.id.servicescard.screens.reactnative.helpers.Student
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromList(Arguments.java:271)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle(Arguments.java:314)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1273)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1185)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.-$$Nest$msetupReactContext(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1139)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
   Process: ca.bc.gov.id.servicescard.dev, PID: 13543
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value type class ca.bc.gov.id.servicescard.screens.reactnative.helpers.Student
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromList(Arguments.java:271)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle(Arguments.java:314)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1273)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1185)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.-$$Nest$msetupReactContext(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1139)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Do you know why this error about unknown value type class?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: This error is thrown because it is expected one of the following types for the element in the list: Array, Bundle, List, String, Integer, Number, Boolean. Otherwise, an error is thrown indicating "Unknown value type {class name}". The array defined is not any of those types: ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();